# How to read data in gspread while column is not aligned properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gspread

Hi I have google sheets where the columns does change daily, if i do `.get_all_records(head=2)` it assumes that the 2nd row is going to be the column name for all records which is not true in my case. My column names does change daily after certain rows.

Note: If I do `.get_all_records(head=2)` columns are being misaligned.

Question: How do I read data in gspread where the column in dynamic/changing frequently?

Thanks